# Perl equivalent of (Postgre)SQL BETWEEN operator?

Tags: perl

Is there such a thing?  The equivalent of `a <= expr <= b`, or in SQL parlance `expr BETWEEN a AND b`, where `expr` is evaluated only once?  Or is asking for this just [getting silly](http://www.perl9.org/?site=Extended-Features/Megahyper-Operators)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do that in Perl.

```
if( $a < $x and $x < $b ){ ... }
... if $a < $x and $x < $b;
```

```
use 5.10.1;
if( $x ~~ [$a..$b] ){ ... }

given( $x ){
  when( [$a..$b] ){ ... }
}
```

```
use 5.11.0; # development branch
given( $x ){
  ... when [$a..$b];
}
```

Comment: Does this work the way you want? I only have 5.10.0 available right now, but the 5.10.1 and 5.11.x manuals don't mention any change for smart matching range operators, and the SCALAR ~~ ARRAY semantics will only work out if you have integers. Now if this were Perl 6, where ranges are their own type...

Comment: Failing test: `ok( 2.5 ~~ [1.3 .. 3.3] )` etc.

Comment: The latter cases are actually more like `$a <= $x <= $b`, and you would have to make sure that `$x` is an integer.

Comment: and's precedence is designed for flow control; I would have used && there.

Comment: @hobbs the `... when [$a..$b]` isn't available in 5.10. As for the `use 5.10.1`, there are some changes to `~~` after 5.10.0 .

Answer (score 6):

you could use [`Range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) + [`smart macthing`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail):

```
if($expr ~~ [$a..$b])
```

Comment: `if( $expr ~~ [a..b] ){ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

In Perl6, the comparison operators are chainable.

http://perlcabal.org/syn/S03.html#Chained_comparisons:

> Perl 6 supports the natural extension to the comparison operators, allowing multiple operands:

```
if 1 < $a < 100 { say "Good, you picked a number *between* 1 and 100." }
if 3 < $roll <= 6              { print "High roll" }
if 1 <= $roll1 == $roll2 <= 6  { print "Doubles!" }
```

In Perl 5, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think they correspond exactly, but take a look at the [Range Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your only bet.

```
$x = expr;

if ($a < $x && $x < $b) {
  # stuff
}
```

Comment: Tempted to -1 for saying "only one way to do it"

Comment: So far, this is the only answer that's correct for things other than integers.